# Javascript alert for ASP.NET (VB) will not appear?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

For some reason my message box will not show up. I type in my code with zero errors, run the page, click the button, and nothing happens. Any idea what's going on?

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub btncheckin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim message As String = "Checked-In!"
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: you are brave for using vb.net

Comment: lol, work for me on c#, do you have some update panels or some ajax in your page?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It should work as expected if this is the only code block you have and you're not hiding anything from us ;)

Comment: Artur I promise it is not by choice!! Haha and Juan I honestly have no idea what that is but I'm assuming that I do not.

Comment: Rahul, what else would you like to see?

Comment: Resulting HTML would be a good starting point...

Comment: or you aspx might be too.

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanels or any other AJAX?  You may need to use `ScriptManager` rather than `ClientScript` if this is the case.

Comment: @ArturPeniche your comment is not warranted. Both VB.Net and C# use the .Net framework - opinions should be kept to yourself!

Comment: @Viper121, when you say `click the button, and nothing happens` does it means that postback is not happening? Or postback occurs but the message is not being shown? If the case is the latter, please verify the html rendered to the browser to see if the script is there, and share it with us.

Comment: You should paste the resulting html. Maybe your message contains a ' that render the js invalid.